# O sistema não está lendo a linha solicitada

Tags: c, dev-c++

Fiz o código abaixo para ler informações de data simples, porém quando o mesmo lê o dia, ele estranhamente pede duas entradas, e acaba indo uma para a variável **diatemp** e o outro para o  **mestemp**, sem chamar o printf("Digite o mês"), isso acaba impossibilitando a continuação do programa, alguém tem alguam sugestão do que eu poderia fazer para solucionar esse problema?

```
void PegarDadosIniciais(){

    //Data dataAtual;

    int diatemp, mestemp, anotemp;

      printf(" @----------------------------------------------------------------------------@\n");
    printf(" | ");printf("\t\t\t     SISTEMA DE LOCACAO DE VEICULOS");printf("\t\t      |\n");
    printf(" @----------------------------------------------------------------------------@\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Bem vindo ao sistema de locacoes de veiculos!! \n");
    printf("%s\n","Precisaremos de alguns dados para iniciar o sistema.." );
    printf("%s\n\n","PRESSIONE ENTER PARA CONTINUAR.." );
    getch();
    system("cls");
    printf(" @----------------------------------------------------------------------------@\n");
    printf(" | ");printf("\t\t\t     CONFIGURACOES INICIAIS");printf("\t\t      |\n");
    printf(" @----------------------------------------------------------------------------@\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n",">>INSIRA A DATA ATUAL<<" );
    printf("%s", "Insira o dia: " );
    scanf("%d\n", &diatemp);
        printf("%s\n","Insira o mes: " );
    scanf("%d\n", &mestemp);
        printf("%s\n","Insira o ano: " );
    scanf("%d\n", &anotemp);
    printf("%d/%d/%d",diatemp, mestemp, anotemp);
    getch();


}
```

Comment: Provavelmente esta pegando o buffer do teclado, coloca outro `getch()` ou use `system("pause")`

Answer (score 1):

O problema está nos `\n` a mais nas leituras com `scanf`:

```
printf("%s", "Insira o dia: " );
scanf("%d\n", &diatemp);
//        ^-- aqui
printf("%s\n","Insira o mes: " );
scanf("%d\n", &mestemp);
//        ^-- aqui
printf("%s\n","Insira o ano: " );
scanf("%d\n", &anotemp);
//        ^-- aqui
```

Isso faz com que o input tenha que levar mais um <kbd>Enter</kbd> sendo que apenas o primeiro valor é consumido.

Correto seria:

```
printf("%s", "Insira o dia: " );
scanf("%d", &diatemp);
printf("%s","Insira o mes: " );
scanf("%d", &mestemp);
printf("%s","Insira o ano: " );
scanf("%d", &anotemp);
```

Algumas observações:

- `printf("%s\n","Insira o mes: " );` Aqui complicou um pouco, bem mais simples era fazer `printf("Insira o mes: \n" );`
- Evite utilizar `getch` pois não é algo portável para outros sistemas operativos.